# Is there any different in rancher version 2.5.5 and 2.6.6?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, cattle

I use 2 ranchers for kubernetes clusters. (2.5.5v, 2.6.6v)
When I create tls secret on rancher version of 2.5.5v, there are annotations about field.cattle.io/... .
But in rancher version of 2.6.6v, there are no annotations about it.
Below is example.

```
## 2.5.5v
kind: Secret
metadata:
  annotations:
    field.cattle.io/algorithm: RSA
    field.cattle.io/certFingerprint: ~~~
    field.cattle.io/cn: '*.example.com'
    field.cattle.io/creatorId: ~~~
    field.cattle.io/expiresAt: "2024-09-15T23:59:59Z"
    field.cattle.io/issuedAt: "2023-08-16T00:00:00Z"
    field.cattle.io/issuer: ~~~
    field.cattle.io/keySize: "256"
    field.cattle.io/serialNumber: ~~~
    field.cattle.io/subjectAlternativeNames: '["*.example.com","example.com"]'
    field.cattle.io/version: "3"
```

Does anyone knows about the difference of rancher version 2.5 and 2.6 ? I checked the data.tls, data.key are correct.

I hope that who give me some solution. I really don't know why it is different.